# Using a variable page type in Frame.Navigate

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

Using WinRT, I am trying to implement navigation based on the users input.  I tried to use a variable page type in the Navigate method.  Unfortunately it doesn't look like it accepts variables as a page type.  Does anybody know a way around this?

```
object myPage = page2;

this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(myPage));
```

I could just create switch statements and put the whole instruction in each statement but that seems ungainly and hard to maintain, especially since I may end up having a great deal of page types.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Edit: A little clarification.  I am writing a quiz program that stores the quizzes in a List, however the are multiple types of quizzes that require specific page formats so I need different page types.  I am storing the the Page type as a string in the List, and the list is randomized so I don't know the next page type from the current test.  The quiz engine will pre read the next quiz in the queue and extract the page type and create a variable to insert into the this.Frame.Navigate command.  This is where I am having the problem.  Any ideas on how to get around this issue?

Thanks

Comment: I ended up getting around this by having all the quiz pages navigate to a results page that then handled the navigation in one spot with a switch statement.  Eventually I'm going to switch to a navigation service instead as implement more MVVM structures.  Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

There is no any "variable" type. `var` just allows you to write less code. Compiler substitutes return type of the expression as the variable type, there's no "magic".

You can write it like this:

```
object myPage;

if (???)
    myPage = new Page1();
else
    myPage = new Page2();

this.Frame.Navigate(myPage.GetType());
```

If you want to implement navigation based on the user's input, you definely need to use if or switch statement. You need to pass type of the page to `Navigate()` method. I don't really get what have you been trying to do with code above. I would do it by using simple if statement.

Comment: I only used var because I wasn't sure of the variable type.  I thought c# was smart enough to figure it out if it was in the right context.

Comment: I tried using object, as you did and most the errors went away, BUT the page didn't navigate.

Comment: @evilsushi I can't reproduce your problem. Can you share the code?